# Adjust step scale with ggplot for slope graph in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, rstudio, scale

I'm drawing a slope graph with ggplot, but the labels get clustered together and are not shown properly because of the scale of the two axis. 
Any idea?

My code and the graph [Is there any way to adjust step scale?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwDUr.png)

Thanks alot!

```
#Read file as numeric data
betterlife<-read.csv("betterlife.csv",skip=4,stringsAsFactors = F)
num_data <- data.frame(data.matrix(betterlife))
numeric_columns <- sapply(num_data,function(x){mean(as.numeric(is.na(x)))<0.5})
final_data <- data.frame(num_data[,numeric_columns], 
betterlife[,!numeric_columns])

## rescale selected columns data frame
final_data <- data.frame(lapply(final_data[,c(3,4,5,6,7,10,11)], function(x) scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/100)))

## Add country names as indicator
final_data["INDICATOR"] <- NA 
final_data$INDICATOR <- betterlife$INDICATOR
employment.data <- final_data[5:30,]
indicator <- employment.data$INDICATOR
## Melt data to draw graph
employment.melt <- melt(employment.data)


#plot
sg = ggplot(employment.melt, aes(factor(variable), value, 
                 group = indicator, 
                 colour = indicator, 
                 label = indicator)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=5),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line("black", size = 0.1),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())
# plot the right-most labels

sg1 = sg + geom_line(size=0.15) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(employment.melt, variable == "Life.expectancy"), 
        aes(x = factor(variable), label=sprintf(" %2f %s",value,INDICATOR)), size = 1.75, hjust = 0) 

# plot the left-most labels

sg1 = sg1 + geom_text(data = subset(employment.melt, variable == "Employment.rate"), 
                 aes(x = factor(variable), label=sprintf("%s %2f ",INDICATOR,value)), size = 1.75, hjust = 1)
sg1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust step scale"? PS: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Let's say I want to add labels to values of 99 and 99.5, I want to set the minimum distance between the two labels so that they dont overlap (as shown in my graph). Tell me if that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set up a scale, for example x (but I think you should do it for y too)

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 5))
```

where 0 - 100 is the range and 5 is the step size. You need to adjust these values according to your graph.
[Source](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)